# How to reduce run time of my code to solve Cycle race practice problem from geeksforgeeks

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am referring to this problem https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/cycle-race/0.

**The Problem description:**

Jack and Jelly are two friends. They want to go to a place by a cycle ( Assume that they live in same house). Distance between the place and their house is 'N' km. Rules of game are as follows:
  - Initially Jelly will ride cycle.
  - They will ride cycle one by one.
  - When one is riding cycle other will sit on the carrier of cycle.
  - In each ride they can ride cycle exactly 1, 2 or 4 km. One cannot ride more than remaining distance.
  - One who reaches school riding cycle will win.
Both play optimally. You have to find who will win this game.

Input:
First line of input contains an integer 'T' denoting the number of test cases. Then 'T' test cases follow. Each test case consists of a single line containing an integer N.

Output:
Print the name of winner i.e 'JACK' or 'JELLY'.

I have written following code for this problem.
Bottom-up approach solution gives me time out.
The top-down approach gives me Segfault. Most probably due to recursion stack. 
How can I improve my solution? 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

**Bottom Up (Timeout):**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool arr[2][10000001];

int main() {
    int t, n;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        cin >> n;

        arr[0][1]=arr[0][2]=arr[0][4]=0;
        arr[1][1]=arr[1][2]=arr[1][4]=1;
        arr[0][3]=1;
        arr[1][3]=0;

        for(int i=5;i<=n;i++) {
            for(int player=0;player<2;player++) {
                if(arr[1-player][i-1]==player||
                   arr[1-player][i-2]==player||
                   arr[1-player][i-4]==player) {
                       arr[player][i] = player;
                   } else {
                       arr[player][i] = 1-player;
                   }
            }
        }

        if(!arr[0][n]) {
            cout << "JELLY" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "JACK" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Top-down (Segfault, I think due to recursion):**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char arr[2][10000001];

bool solve(int n, bool player) {
    if(arr[player][n] != -1)
        return arr[player][n];
    if(solve(n-1,!player) == player ||
       solve(n-2,!player) == player ||
       solve(n-4,!player) == player) {
           arr[player][n] = player;
    } else {
        arr[player][n] = !player;
    }
    return arr[player][n];
}

int main() {
    int t, n;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        cin >> n;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++) {
                arr[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }

        arr[0][1]=arr[0][2]=arr[0][4]=0;
        arr[1][1]=arr[1][2]=arr[1][4]=1;
        arr[0][0]=arr[0][3]=1;
        arr[1][0]=arr[1][3]=0;

        solve(n, false);

        if(!arr[0][n]) {
            cout << "JELLY" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "JACK" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code work at all? I mean does it ever return a valid result, e.g. for small samples?

Comment: Yes. I have posted the code which passes the submission criteria.

Comment: If you add the description of the original task to the question I'll give you two votes ;-)

Comment: I have included the link in my question where the original task has been described.

Comment: Please summarise the requirements (in your own words) *in the body of the question*.  Unlike a diamond, a link is not forever - and we want your question to be able to survive the disappearance of the linked resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. It is actually testing the game theory. If we see the pattern then only when n is a multiple of 3 then only whoever starts the game first will loose and in all other cases who starts the game will win. The working code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, n;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        cin >> n;
        if( n%3 == 0) {
            cout << "JACK" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "JELLY" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```